# Reading XML from a GPX file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, gpx

I would like to extract and `strinfigy` the XML from a given `.gpx` file using Javascript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsText(acceptedFiles[0])
reader.onloadend = () => {
  console.log(reader.result)
}
```